# Confusion in "smallest width dp" in Android

Tags: android, android-selector

I am learning how to use "smallest width dp" to support different screens using [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) in android.

i get that below number are the smallest of side of device in dp.

> Typical numbers for screen width dp are:
>
> 320: a phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
>
> 480: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
>
> 600: a 7” tablet (600x1024).
>
> 720: a 10” tablet (720x1280, 800x1280, etc).

According to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) post nexus 6 has 730 x 410 dp.

> The Nexus 6 boasts an impressive 5.96” Quad HD screen display at a
>   resolution of 2560 x 1440 (493 ppi). This translates to ~ 730 x 410 dp
>   (density independent pixels).

but as explained in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

```
           dp = (px/dpi)*160
              = (1440/493)*160
              = ~467
```

then how come this translates to 730 x **410** dp?
further more when i run the demo in nexus 6, device is using padding dimension defined under res/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml

this confuses me. how does one actually calculates dp and create view accordingly using "smallest width dp" ?

apart from res/values-sw320dp i have res/value and res/values-sw600dp that has dimens.xml under it.

**UPDATE** figured out my confusion. check comment under question.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105032/confusion-with-smallest-width-600-dp-selector)... it may help u

Comment: I figured it out using this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041594/how-does-quantized-density-affect-image-resource-selection-and-scaling).

dp is calculated by quantized density not physical density. so 730 x 410 dp  for nexus 6 is correct.

Comment: And sw320dp part confusion was my mistake in understanding.  res/values-sw320dp is used because next bucket defined is  res/values-sw600dp which obviously is larger that 410(min side if nexus 6).

Answer (score 7):

You can get the correct values with the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    Log.d("dpHeight-----",String.valueOf(dpHeight));
    Log.d("dpWidth------",String.valueOf(dpWidth));
```

For example for the Xperia Z 1080x1920px the values are **360**x592dp, the settings is **values-sw360dp**

Comment: yes, this gives right values. DisplayMetrics.density is used for scaling resources which depends on quantized density.